# Transaction on Uniswap -- how to find out what pair is being swapped (via web3.js)?

Tags: web3js, transactions, uniswap, pending-transactions, raw-transaction

Given a transaction on Uniswap,

[image]

how to find out what pair is being swapped, and the amount of it? Namely, via web3.js/ethers.js

Is there relevant and sufficient information in the fields of a transction? Or will one have to make additional calls?

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the transaction input using `UniswapV2Router abi`. Look at this part of ethers' documentation: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/. Especially at the `parseTransaction` method.